# Not able to convert a string to XML

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml

I am passing XML as a string to a method and again converting that in XML to do my work.

Its working fine normally, but when there are special character like `&` or `=` it's giving an error.

My XML string:

```
<SuggestedReadings>
   <Suggestion Text="Customer Centricity" Link="http://wdp.wharton.upenn.edu/book/customer-centricity/?utm_source=Coursera&utm_medium=Web&utm_campaign=custcent" SuggBy="Pete Fader�s" />
   <Suggestion Text="Global Brand Power" Link="http://wdp.wharton.upenn.edu/books/global-brand-power/?utm_source=Coursera&utm_medium=Web&utm_campaign=glbrpower" SuggBy="Barbara Kahn�s" />
</SuggestedReadings>
```

My code is:

```
public class saveData(string strXml)
{
      XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
      xmlDoc.LoadXml(CD.SRList);// here its giving error
}
```

Error :

> '=' is an unexpected token. The expected token is ';'. Line 1, position 150.

Complete error is:

> System.Xml.XmlException was unhandled by user code HResult=-2146232000
>   Message='=' is an unexpected token. The expected token is ';'. Line 1,
>   position 150. Source=System.Xml LineNumber=1 LinePosition=150
>   SourceUri="" StackTrace:    at
>   System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.Throw(Exception e)    at
>   System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.Throw(String res, String[] args)    at
>   System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.ThrowUnexpectedToken(String
>   expectedToken1, String expectedToken2)    at
>   System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.ThrowUnexpectedToken(Int32 pos, String
>   expectedToken1, String expectedToken2)    at
>   System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.HandleEntityReference(Boolean
>   isInAttributeValue, EntityExpandType expandType, Int32& charRefEndPos)
>   at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.ParseAttributeValueSlow(Int32 curPos,
>   Char quoteChar, NodeData attr)    at
>   System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.ParseAttributes()    at
>   System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.ParseElement()    at
>   System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.ParseElementContent()    at
>   System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.Read()    at
>   System.Xml.XmlLoader.LoadNode(Boolean skipOverWhitespace)    at
>   System.Xml.XmlLoader.LoadDocSequence(XmlDocument parentDoc)    at
>   System.Xml.XmlLoader.Load(XmlDocument doc, XmlReader reader, Boolean
>   preserveWhitespace)    at System.Xml.XmlDocument.Load(XmlReader
>   reader)    at System.Xml.XmlDocument.LoadXml(String xml)    at
>   ICA.LMS.Service.Controllers.AdminCourseApiController.SaveCourse(CourseDetails
>   CD) in d:\Live
>   Projects\ICA_LMS\ICA_LMS_WebAPI\Controllers\AdminCourseApiController.cs:line
>   122    at lambda_method(Closure , Object , Object[] )    at
>   System.Web.Http.Controllers.ReflectedHttpActionDescriptor.ActionExecutor.<>c__DisplayClass10.b__9(Object
>   instance, Object[] methodParameters)    at
>   System.Web.Http.Controllers.ReflectedHttpActionDescriptor.ActionExecutor.Execute(Object
>   instance, Object[] arguments)    at
>   System.Web.Http.Controllers.ReflectedHttpActionDescriptor.ExecuteAsync(HttpControllerContext
>   controllerContext, IDictionary`2 arguments, CancellationToken
>   cancellationToken)    InnerException:

Comment: What is `CD.SRList`?

Comment: its actually the ampersand which is incorrectly escaped. its just expecting it to be an escaped character in the form &something; so when it gets to the = it throws the error.

Comment: @JenishRabadiya thsi is holding the xml string.....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your document is missing the XML header, which is required. Also, you are not correctly escaping the `&` character.

Try adding this on top of your XML document:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

And also replace `&` with `&amp;`. (See the [list of characters to escape](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1091945/993547))

Comment: @Raghubar: I just tested it and the `XmlDocument` doesn't require the XML header, while according to the specs it should have it. So for this time you can omit it, but please edit it in.

Comment: its working. But new problem has been occured, the code i have written for read the xml not working. so please post some code to read this xml nodes value.

Answer (score 2):

`&` is special character in XML. Try to use `&amp;` instead of `&`

```
<SuggestedReadings>
   <Suggestion Text="Customer Centricity" Link="http://wdp.wharton.upenn.edu/book/customer-centricity/?utm_source=Coursera&amp;utm_medium=Web&amp;utm_campaign=custcent" SuggBy="Pete Fader�s" />
   <Suggestion Text="Global Brand Power" Link="http://wdp.wharton.upenn.edu/books/global-brand-power/?utm_source=Coursera&amp;utm_medium=Web&amp;utm_campaign=glbrpower" SuggBy="Barbara Kahn�s" />
</SuggestedReadings>
```

Answer (score 1):

its actually the ampersand which is incorrectly escaped. its just expecting it to be an escaped character in the form &something; so when it gets to the = it throws the error.

```
[TestMethod]
public void BadXml()
{
    string xml = "<SuggestedReadings><Suggestion Text=\"Customer Centricity\" Link=\"http://wdp.wharton.upenn.edu/book/customer-centricity/?utm_source=Coursera&utm_medium=Web&utm_campaign=custcent\" SuggBy=\"Pete Fader�s\" /><Suggestion Text=\"Global Brand Power\" Link=\"http://wdp.wharton.upenn.edu/books/global-brand-power/?utm_source=Coursera&utm_medium=Web&utm_campaign=glbrpower\" SuggBy=\"Barbara Kahn�s\" /></SuggestedReadings>";

    XmlDocument xdoc = new XmlDocument();
    xml = xml.Replace("&", "&amp;");
    xdoc.LoadXml(xml);

}
```

Answer (score 1):

> XML predefines the following five entity references for special
>   characters that would otherwise be interpreted as part of markup
>   language

```
<   ->  &lt;
>   ->  &gt;
"   ->  &quot;
'   ->  &apos;
&   ->  &amp;
```

> You can use entity and character references to escape the left angle
>   bracket, the ampersand, and other delimiters. You can also use numeric
>   character references. Numeric character references are expanded
>   immediately when they are recognized. In addition, because numeric
>   character references are treated as character data, you can use the
>   numeric character references

Hope this links will help you.

How to locate and replace special characters in an XML file with Visual C# .NET
https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/316063

Different ways how to escape an XML string in C#
http://weblogs.sqlteam.com/mladenp/archive/2008/10/21/Different-ways-how-to-escape-an-XML-string-in-C.aspx